# For-loop doesn't loop through graph's data

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, graph

I want to edit the graph so it displays my results from my two arrays.
The code I want to edit is on: http://jsfiddle.net/mahbub/2Dv3E/

I replaced `var links` with my own for loop:

```
var z;
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"]; 
var person = ["David", "Joe", "Harry"];

for(z=0;z<5;z++){
var links = [
{
    source: cars[z],
    target: person[z]
}];
}
```

**The output I want is** to create a graph with Saab linked to David, Volvo linked to Joe and BMW linked to Harry

**The problem is** that my for loop doesn't loop `var links` therefore it outputs only one link, not 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The problem:

For each iteration of the loop you are:

- declaring a variable `link`
- assign the value of `link` to an array containing an object. **You are not adding to the array.**. You are overwriting any previous value with the current object
- you end up with a variable called `link` whose value is the object that was set on the_last_ iteration of the loop

#### Suggested solution:

Use [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to add items to an array that was declared and instantiated outside of the `for` loop:

```
// declare links outside of for loop and before it
// initialise is value to an empty array
var links = [];

// The condition this loop will stop will be
// the length of the cars array
// This should avoid creating unwanted values in your links array
// by stopping array for the number of elements
// present in the cars array
for(z=0; z<cars.length; z++){

  // "push" your object into links array
  // for each iteration of the loop
  links.push({
               source: cars[z],
               target: person[z]
            });
}
```

Comment: Glad this helped!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be creating an object then pushing it to links:

```
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"]; 
var person = ["David", "Joe", "Harry"];
var links = [];
for(var z = 0; z < cars.length; z++){
 links.push({source: cars[z],
             target: person[z]
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to push each item to the links array like this:

```
    var z;
    var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"]; 
    var person = ["David", "Joe", "Harry"];
    var links = [{
        source: "2335656544544",
        target: "2335656544589"
    }, {
        source: "2335656544544",
        target: "2335656544590"
    }, {
        source: "2335656544544",
        target: "2335656544591"
    }];

for(z = 0; z < 5; z++){
    links.push({
        source: cars[z],
        target: person[z]
    });
}
```